# Can't run react native on my virtual device

Tags: react-native, mobile-development

I'm following React Native's own setup guide for setting my React Native 0.70 envorinment but whenever I'm writing **'npm run android'** in the Android Studio terminal I get this error:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> Where:
> Script 'C:\Users\mtepe\OneDrive\Masa�st�\react-native\firstProject\node_modules@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\native_modules.gradle' line: 413
>
> What went wrong:
> A problem occurred evaluating script.
> node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1080  throw err;  ^Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\mtepe\OneDrive\MasaÃ¼stÃ¼\react-native\firstProject\node_modules@react-native-community\cli\b
> uild\bin.js'    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1077:15)    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:27)    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',  requireStack: []}Node.js v18.17.0
>
> Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
>
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BU�LD FAILED in 2s
>
> error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
> Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
>
> > :ReactNative:Unexpected empty result of running '[node, C:\Users\mtepe\OneDrive\Masaüstü\react-native\firstProject\node_modules@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js, config]' command.
> > :ReactNative:Running '[node, C:\Users\mtepe\OneDrive\Masaüstü\react-native\firstProject\node_modules@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js, config]' command failed.
> > BU�LD FAILED in 2s
>
> at makeError (C:\Users\mtepe\OneDrive\Masaüstü\react-native\firstProject\node_modules@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
> at C:\Users\mtepe\OneDrive\Masaüstü\react-native\firstProject\node_modules@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
> at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
> at async runOnAllDevices (C:\Users\mtepe\OneDrive\Masaüstü\react-native\firstProject\node_modules@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:109:5)
> at async Command.handleAction (C:\Users\mtepe\OneDrive\Masaüstü\react-native\firstProject\node_modules@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:142:9)
> info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

I'm stuck with this error for a day now. Any help is appreciated.

I followed [https://reactnative.dev/docs/0.70/environment-setup?platform=android&os=windows] this guide over and over but despite installing the correct versions I'm getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try reseting metro cache. `npx react-native start --reset-cache`.
2. Rerun install scripts if that step doesn't work. Make sure to remove your node_modules as they could be needing a refresh.
3. If all these do not work out, try creating a new react-native project and see if it builds. If it's successful, you may want to convert your project to the same version of react-native. If it fails too then my guess is something in your environment is not compatible.

Example init script `npx react-native@0.70.11 init AwesomeProject --version 0.70.11`

Questions:

1. Regarding your path, it looks like you have special characters maybe accents? Might be worth renaming the path to a pure alphanumerical structure. Also avoid spaces in paths if possible. Special characters and spaces can break some less resilient scripts.
2. Did you recently upgrade node? Node 18.17.0 was just released (4 days ago). So that could be part of the reason things aren't working. It's possible one or more of your dependencies are not compatible with 18.17.0. Try downgrading to whatever version was used in your project previously (maybe 16 or <=18.16.1) check for a `.nvmrc` or `_node-version` file

FYI for node management look at [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) or [fnm](https://github.com/Schniz/fnm). They make it extremely easy to swap and install versions of node. Fnm is much faster but nvm is more a community standard.

Comment: Thank you for your solution. I thought about the path so I tried running React Native in a different path that only includes English characters and it worked.